# E_INVALIDARG CreatePixelShader() Error

Tags: c++, windows-8, directx

I  have the following code:

```
struct shaderData
{
    char *shaderCode;
    UINT size;
};

struct shaderData *CubeApp::GetShaderByteCode(char *compiledShader)
{
    struct shaderData *sData = (struct shaderData *)malloc(sizeof(struct shaderData));

    std::ifstream fin(compiledShader, std::ios::binary);

    fin.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
    UINT size = (int)fin.tellg();
    fin.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);

    sData->shaderCode = (char *)malloc(size);

    fin.read(sData->shaderCode, size);
    fin.close();

    sData->size = size;

    return sData;
}

void CubeApp::InitShaders()
{
    struct shaderData *sData = GetShaderByteCode("PShader.cso");

    HRESULT hr = m_d3dDevice->CreatePixelShader(sData->shaderCode, sData->size, NULL, &m_d3dPShader);
}
```

But this returns E_INVALIDARG when calling CreatePixelShader(), and m_d3dPShader is a NULL pointer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does PShader.cso file contain compiled shader or source code?

Comment: Compiled shader code from fxc.exe (im using visual studio 2012 on windows 8)

Comment: wow. I  just lowered the shader model from 5.0 to 4.0.. i thought my graphics card was capable of shader model 5... ended up working. Thanks for leading me in the right direction. haha

Comment: Really right direction :) BTW, DirectX Debug mode can help in such situations: http://blog.rthand.com/post/2010/10/25/Capture-DirectX-1011-debug-output-to-Visual-Studio.aspx

Comment: Well.. this is odd, i compile with shader model 4.0, CreatePixelShader() works... but i know my graphics card ( GeForce GT 440) supports DirectX 11.. which should mean I have Shader Model 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

This was exactly my problem. My hardware shows and reports support for DirectX 11_0, however compiling my vertex or pixel shader with a profile of vs_5_0 or ps_5_0 resulted in  CreateVertexShader() | CreatePixelShader() returning with E_INVALIDARG.

Once I recompiled the shaders with a profile of vs_4_0, ps_4_0 the calls returned S_OK.